# UI has to be developed in SWT with RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

My requirement is to develop UI with SWT. I was told I have to use RCP software which is going to be Eclipse Luna. After doing enough research, I also tried making plugin  in eclipse as the online tutorial . But I could not understand where exactly I can develop UI which should have controls like Text box, drop-down box etc. What do I do with the plug in eclipse ? Does it serve any purpose in creating UI in SWT?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are many good books on writing Eclipse plug-ins; you can find those on Amazon. I'm not linking to them because I wrote one of them and don't want to appear biased. But this kind of information is trivially findable through a search engine or other resources already on the internet.

Comment: Sorry but this way too broad. You can use Eclipse to develop a simple app which just uses SWT or you can use it to write a RCP using the [Eclipse 4 (e4) style](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) or the [Eclipse 3.x compatibility style](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html)

Comment: Hi greg, can you tell me how can I  develop simple desktop app using SWT.. do you suggest any tutorial? I have to start developing the application, but I don't know what to do for developing an interface itself(presentation layer ) first?

Comment: Maybe you should start with [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html).

Answer (score 2):

Please go through some good tutorials at [Vogella RCP tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html). Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the links you have been provided. I will suggest you to start UI design using [WindowsBuilder](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWindowBuilder/article.html). It will give you good and easy start to design interface.

Comment: Bad advice.  A WindowBuilder will confuse you way more than help you, unless you've already constructed hundreds of SWT GUIs by hand.

Comment: I would say for beginners, its better to start just drag and drop UI component initially and get the base interface than writhing each components in java code to get the same interface.